# Background subsection required when publishing a translated Google Docs Add-on

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, chrome-web-store

I developped a Google Docs add-on with translations, so, instead of using the traditional online deployment process, I need to upload a ZIP file with a json manifest (example below) and files for each locales.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "__MSG_application_title__",
"short_name": "__MSG_application_title__",
"description": "__MSG_application_description__",
"container": ["GOOGLE_DOCUMENT"],
"default_locale": "en",
"icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
},
"container_info": {
    "container_version": "my_container_version",
    "post_install_tip": "my_tip",
  "container_id": "my_container_id"
},
"version": "my_version"
}
```

When uploading such ZIP file, I get the following error message:

> An error occurred: Failed to process your item. Please specify
>   background subsection of app section in the manifest. Legacy packaged
>   apps cannot be uploaded to the Chrome Web Store any more. More
>   information can be found at
>   http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html

I tried to add background subsection from different ways, but none of them was working. Does anyone know how to change the manifest to make it valid please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sincerest apologies, I was misunderstanding the issue entirely. Try and see if:

```
  "app":{
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  }
  },
```

Works when added to your code.

Comment: It was the only way recommended by Google to publish an Add-on with translations in several languages.

Do you know how to translate an Chrome Web Store app without uploading a ZIP file ? Thanks

Comment: This is the tooltip when you publish your add-on "Upload a new ZIP file to update the manifest (which specifies information such as the name, short description, version, and permissions) or to update any other files that are part of the package that the user downloads from the store. Don’t forget to increment the version number! More info" https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish?hl=en#step2. It's impossible to uploaded an unzipped version

Answer (score 0):

similarly, I had to change the app section of my manifest to the following to get it to work when facing this issue:

```
"app": {
      "background": {
          "persistent": false
      }
  }
```